# Show an image stored on internal storage

Tags: java, android

I'm developing an Android application and I do this to save a bitmap into internal storage:

```
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap profilePicture)
    {
        FileOutputStream fOut = null;

        try
        {
            fOut = openFileOutput(Constants.FB_PROFILE_IMAGE_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            profilePicture.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, fOut);
            fOut.flush();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                fOut.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        loadingDialog.dismiss();
    }
```

**How can I do to open it and show it into an `ImageView`?**

This code doesn't work because `imgFile` doesn't exist:

```
private void loadAndShowUserProfileImage()
{
    File imgFile = new  File(Constants.FB_PROFILE_IMAGE_FILE_NAME);
    if(imgFile.exists())
    {
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());

        userImageProfile.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
FileInputStream fIn = openFileInput(Constants.FB_PROFILE_IMAGE_FILE_NAME);
Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fIn);
```

`openFileOutput/openFileInput` should be always used in pair